# codeigniter project is not running in cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I have done a project on Codeigniter and uploaded that on my domain like domain/project but its not running.It shows an `error page not found` ! I have changed my config file  and have edited database.php also but still no running and throwing this error can any body help me ?

here is the config setup

```
     $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/crm/';
```

and in the  the database.php

```
       'hostname' => 'localhost',
       'username' => 'root',
       'password' => '',
       'database' => 'crm_valentine',
       'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

the htaccess inside my project  file's are

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i tried both but it produce this error 
Internal Server Error

```
  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was      unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@bdprogrammer.com to     inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just   before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

    Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while   trying    to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: did u check the .htaccess

Comment: the htaccess inside my project  file's are

Comment: try this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /projectname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: chnage ur base url from `http://localhost/crm/` to  `http://domainname/crm/`

Comment: i tried both but it produce this erro

Comment: remove htaccess and than give a try

Comment: when i remove .htaccess then it show                                                      404 Page Not Found  The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 1):

As Viky pointed out you need to change the `base_url` in your config.
Then make sure you  are using that path. If you uploaded a `project` folder then you need to make it `domain/project` not `domain/crm`.
Make sure the database exists on your server.

And, most important, check the error logs for further hints of what went wrong.

Comment: crm is my project folder's name . i changed config file to mydomain/crm  and i have database in phpmyadmin .

Comment: then you should see at least a custom 404 from the framework.  
search for the php error logs and see what's there

Comment: in my domain there is my wordpress site's file and beside them i have my crm project folder . Did this make any problem . and where i can find the error log file @the-noob

Comment: it won't work because you have the Wordpress htaccess that will override the one in your `crm` project. not sure where the error log is on your setup, just look in CPanel for something like Logs. Some hosting companies put a `logs` symlink outside your `htdocs`

Comment: in my domain there is a log file but it show's some error that is one month earlier .@the-noob

Comment: that means you never hit your project, that's because of the `htaccess` from wordpress . if you access directly the index page you should be able to see your project (`domain/crm/index.php`)